# Zapcat Zabbix 2.0

Tags: zabbix

I've problem when configure zapcat on zabbix 2.0 followed link

http://www.kjkoster.org/zapcat/Tomcat_How_To.html

Then I try to use JMX but an error occured when run :

**java -Dcom.sun.management.jxmremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.2.56 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true**

and error is :

**Error: Password file read access must be restricted: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password**

So any solution for me ??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Zapcat with Zabbix 2.0.  Look up using the Zabbix Java Gateway instead:  https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/concepts/java

However for this error.  You need to set the restriction on your password conf file to chmod 600.